# Adding key/value into array where value is a object

Tags: javascript, jquery

Adding key/value into array where value is a object

I want to add some text as a key and Object as a value.

Example

```
$('#clickme').on('click' , function() {
    push to array => "some_text" as (value) and $(this) as key
})
```

Comment: you can't have a non numeric key for arrays in javascript

Comment: thank you for the reply, what would be the best approach for this?

Comment: store what you require as object properties

Comment: Tried `$(this).data(value)`? See http://api.jquery.com/data/ and http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

Answer (score 6):

Just use a normal object which works as an associative array anyway:

```
var myObj = {};
$('#clickme').on('click' , function() {
    myObj["some_text"] = $(this);
});
```

Comment: sorry to be dumb... but how can i get back the text associated with the object.

Comment: `var value = myObj["some_text"];`

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
var myArr = new Array();
myArr["MyKey"] = { name: "myobject" };
```